# How do I avoid repeating the use of the put() method while using Maps?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, put, repeat

So basically I have this HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Double[]> list = new HashMap<>();
```

And values(the macro and micro nutrients of foods which I want to save):

```
Double[] orange = {11.7, 0.9, 0.1, 4.0, 89.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.1, 4.0, 5.0, 47.0};

Double[] broccoli = {7.2, 2.4, 0.4, 31.0, 108.0, 7.0, 176.0, 30.0, 45.0, 23.0, 4.0, 3.0, 11.0};

list.put("orange", orange);

list.put("broccoli", broccoli);
```

Now I have more foods than these, so I wanted to shrink all "list.put()" to one. Maybe using a for loop. And using another String array with the food names to iterate each on the for. Any tips on how to organize what I want to do here? Thanks.

The rest of my code if needed is here: https://pastebin.com/Vw2UerDG

Comment: Why is your map named `list`?

Comment: Store all of the values (and their names) in a **file**. Parse the file to create your `Map`. Avoid hardcoding magic numbers.

Comment: My mistake that I named it list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Java version, you can do it like this:

```
Double[] orange = {11.7, 0.9, 0.1,  4.0, 89.0,   1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 2.0,   0.1, 4.0, 5.0,    47.0};
Double[] broccoli = {7.2, 2.4, 0.4,  31.0,108.0, 7.0,176.0,30.0, 45.0, 23.0, 4.0, 3.0,    11.0};

String[]   keys   = {"orange", "broccoli"};
Double[][] values = {orange  , broccoli  };

Map<String, Double[]> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    map.put(keys[i], values[i]);
```

In Java 9+, and if you have 10 or fewer map entries, you can simplify it like this:

```
Double[] orange = {11.7, 0.9, 0.1,  4.0, 89.0,   1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 2.0,   0.1, 4.0, 5.0,    47.0};
Double[] broccoli = {7.2, 2.4, 0.4,  31.0,108.0, 7.0,176.0,30.0, 45.0, 23.0, 4.0, 3.0,    11.0};

Map<String, Double[]> map = Map.of(
        "orange"  , orange,
        "broccoli", broccoli );
```

And if you don't need the `Double[]` to be named, you can inline them:

```
Map<String, Double[]> map = Map.of(
        "orange", new Double[] {11.7, 0.9, 0.1,  4.0, 89.0,   1.0, 0.0,  1.0, 2.0,   0.1, 4.0, 5.0,    47.0},
        "broccoli", new Double[] {7.2, 2.4, 0.4,  31.0,108.0, 7.0,176.0,30.0, 45.0, 23.0, 4.0, 3.0,    11.0} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Till Java-8 there is no standard method provided by Java API to put multiple key-value without using `put` method multiple time. However Java-9 API provides a factory method `Map#of` , you can use it build your map using by passing key value.

```
Map.of("<Key1>", "<Value1>", "<Key2>", "<Value2>");
```

Note: `Map#of` returns an immutable map.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class which hold `name` and (list of) `nutrients`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit orange = new Fruit(
                "orange",
                new Double[]{0.9, 0.1, 4.0, 89.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.1, 4.0, 5.0, 47.0}
        );
        Fruit broccoli = new Fruit(
                "broccoli",
                new Double[]{7.2, 2.4, 0.4, 31.0, 108.0, 7.0, 176.0, 30.0, 45.0, 23.0, 4.0, 3.0, 11.0}
        );

        List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(orange, broccoli));

        Map<String, Double[]> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (Fruit fruit : fruitList) {
            map.put(fruit.getName(), fruit.getNutrients());
        }

    }
}

class Fruit {

    private String name;
    private Double[] nutrients;

    Fruit(String name, Double[] nutrients) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nutrients = nutrients;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Double[] getNutrients() {
        return nutrients;
    }
}
```